# custom android dialog with buttons the same size

Tags: android, button, dialog, width

I've written my own timer picker, displayed in a custom dialog. I used TableLayout and layout_weight="1" to achieve a grid pattern containing 9 equal sized Button and EditText widgets (this part works fine). At the bottom I want the Ok and Cancel buttons to be the same width as each other, occupying about half of the width of the dialog. I tried layout_width="1" but the button sizes don't come out the same width, but they're close enough. This isn't so bad, except when the screen is in the landscape orientation, the buttons are displayed left-justified, without any padding around the text. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mike,

I have something similar in one o my apps, here's the code that should give you what you're looking for, just place this inside your existing dialog...

```
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonGroup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/DialogText"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button android:id="@+id/dialogOkButton" 
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/lblSet"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/dialogCancelButton" 
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/lblCancel"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

The LinearLayout is what makes it stretch across the parent view.  Please keep in mind, you need to place this inside your layout, so the LinearLayout is within your layout.  I'm kinda tired so sorry if I'm rambling :-P

Comment: Thank you Jared. This worked great. I thought I tried LinearLayout inside by TableLayout already, but I must have made a mistake. I think layout_width="0dip" is what I missed before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do sth similar to what Jared proposed, but set layout_width="fill_parent" on the buttons, and layout_weight="0.5".  If you want one of the buttons to be longer than the other, set its weight to say 0.3 and the other one 0.7